# Should I use "some day" or "someday" in this context?

Tags: difference

A mother is talking to her baby --

***You're going to be a very handsome man some day/someday. Yes, you are. Just like your dad.***

(I have read about the difference between "some day" and "someday" but I find it very confusing and I still don't know what to use in this context, so could you please help me)

1. What do I want here -- "some day" or "someday"?
2. Would using "one day" also be appropriate?
3. Is "yes, you are" correct? Would "yes, you will" also be correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, it depends on what you mean. As [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/someday-vs-some-day/) explains very simply:

> ***Someday*** means “at an indefinite time in the future.”
>
> ***Some day*** refers to one day that is perhaps unknown or unspecified.

2. Yes, you can use ***one day*** instead, with the same meaning as "some day".
3. "Yes, you are" is correct, because it refers to the verb used in the preceding sentence "you are going to be".

Would "yes, you will" also be correct? Normally, you should use an elliptic sentence referring to a preceding one, using the same auxiliary of the verb. However, I do not see why we could not use it to give another stronger connotation to what has just been said:

> You're going to be a very handsome man some day/someday. Yes, you ***will*** (definitely, surely, I bet my life on it). Just like your dad.